# Pod install removing the React after upgrading the react-native version

Tags: react-native

While running the pod install it removing the React after upgrading the react-native version. So I am facing the error **'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found**

```
/Applications/helloworld/node_modules/bugsnag-react-native/cocoa/BugsnagReactNative.h:3:9: 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found
```

Comment: have you tried removing use_frameworks in your pod?

Comment: No I not added it in my podfile